# macOS: Get rights for task_for_pid()

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to call task_for_pid() in my program. I created a **self signed** certificate and added "SecTaskAccess" to Info.plist. I'm using Security/Authorization.h but task_for_pid() fails.

```
OSStatus status;
AuthorizationItem item[] = {{"system.privilege.taskport:"}};
AuthorizationRights rights = {1, item}, *rightsGot = nullptr;
AuthorizationRef author;

AuthorizationFlags authFlags = kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | ( 1 << 5);
status = AuthorizationCreate(nullptr, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, authFlags, &author);
if(status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
{
    return false;
}
status = AuthorizationCopyRights(author, &rights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, authFlags, &rightsGot);
if(status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
{
    return false;
}
if(task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), m_pid, &m_task) != KERN_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to get task from pid" << std::endl;
    return false;    //Fails here
}
```